# Configurate tasks.json file in VS Code to compile C++ with specific version of C++ on Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, compilation, g++, clang

I am trying to compile some C++ code using VS Code and have some trouble with using different C++ version. I would like to compile it with an option `-std=c++17` as some things I need to test out work in C++17 only (By default, Clang uses C++14).
So, I tried editing my *tasks.json* file to manually add an option to use C++17. However, even after doing that nothing seems to work.

Initially, I only edited the `options` part for *g++ build active file* but , as it didn't seem to work, I added that option to all tasks. Unfortunately, this didn't help either. Can you tell me where exactly I made a mistake there?
You can find *tasks* part of *tasks,json* file below.

```
"tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-std=c++17"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What exactly does "*nothing seems to work*" and "*didn't help either*" mean? Did the compilation fail? What errors or log messages do you get in VS Code's console output? How are you running the task? (Tasks: Run Task > g++ build active file)? Have you tried running the `g++` command outside of VS Code to confirm it *can* be compiled correctly on your machine?

Comment: Standard compilation in VS Code(-std=c++11 and earlier), as well as compilation in terminal work fine. I found a solution to my problem though, so I guess I will just post the answer myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the answer was simple , and I was actually doing the right things but in the wrong place.

First of all, it is possible just to add `-std=c++17` to any of your tasks manually or just make a separate task with a specific name. As an example(taken from a VS Code website),

```
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
```

This is a task that has a name `clang++ build active file` and uses `std=c++17` as a C++ version. Then, instead of pressing the *Run code* button you would have to use *Terminal->Run build task* option.

I initially though there would be a way to override the *Run code* button behaviour to use a different C++ version, but I guess the only way to do it is through adding a new/editing an old task.